# Missing hyperlinks in apxproof

Tags: hyperref, lncs, proof-package

I'm using apxproof and I would like lemmas and theorems to share a counter. The counter is working fine; however, forward links are appearing for only the theorems and not the lemmas (backwards links from appendix to main text are all fine). It seems to be a specific issue with the llncs class -- the links appear as desired for the article class, or when separate counters are used.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage[bibliography=common]{apxproof}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newtheoremrep{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheoremrep{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{theoremrep}
theorem text
\end{theoremrep}
\begin{proof}
proof text
\end{proof}

\begin{lemmarep}
lemma text
\end{lemmarep}
\begin{proof}
lemma proof
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I recommend contacting the author of `apxproof` since it is supposed to be compatible with `llcns`. At the very least, if there are limitations on how you should use the package, they should be documented. I'm not sure how `llcns`'s definition of `lemma` interacts with  yours, but there seems some potential for conflict there, for example.